# Eclipse Mars exit code = 13 error

Tags: java, eclipse, ini

Im trying to open my new eclipse for java but I keep getting an error saying "Java was started but returned exit code=13" I already tried adding the `-vm C:\Program File (x86)\Java\1.8.0\jre\bin\javaw.exe` line but the error still keeps popping up. What am I doing wrong?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins       
/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\1.8.0\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\1.8.0\jre\bin\javaw.exe` means 32-bit Java.  `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417` means a 64-bit Eclipse. They have to match. Go get the 32-bit Eclipse for Java EE download.

Comment: 32-bit works! But its kinda wired though because my machine tells me its 64-bit. What should I do if I want the 64-bit version?

Comment: Also make absolutely sure you have a 64-bit Java installed and that it's the one being used to run that 64-bit Eclipse.